# Grouping of permutations in java and sorting simple ones come first

Tags: java

hi I have a list that contains the strings as like

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("HP60002H-HP60002H-HP60002H");
    list.add("HP60003H");
    list.add("SY12049H-SY12049H-HP60002H");
    list.add("SY12049H-SY12049H-SY12049H");
    list.add("SY12049H-HP60002H-SY12049H");
```

and i want list of strings grouped like and sorting the simplest ones first 
like List finalList= new ArrayList() which contains the strings as follows

```
HP60003H 
SY12049HX3
HP60002HX3
SY12049HX2 - HP60002H
SY12049H-HP60002H-SY12049H
```

Comment: I dont get how your output should look in the end. Do you want to have every single element like "HP6002H" and "SY12049H" in a list or should it be still as "SY12049H-HP60002H-SY12049H" etc but sorted?

Comment: You seem to want to translate the literal  `"HP60002H-HP60002H-HP60002H"` to `"HP60002HX3"`, and `"SY12049H-SY12049H-HP60002H"` to `"SY12049HX2-HP60002H"` is that right? And then you want the sort to be based first on "simplicity" (e.g. length of the string after translation), then by number after the X, then by alphabet.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
TreeSet<String> finalList = new TreeSet<String>();

for(String aString : list){
    String[] splitted = aString.split("-");
    finalList.addAll(Arrays.asList(splitted));
}

System.out.println(finalList);
```

Probably not the best solution but should work.

TreeSet holds the set in a tree structure which is automatically sorted in natural order. Because the String class implements the Comparable interface it will be sorted automatically.

EDIT:

Now I understand what you actually want to do.

Well, you need to loop through your list, split by "-". Then you loop through all splitted strings and count the same strings and add "X" + counter to it. After that you concat all same strings with "-" and add it to a collection. In the end you need to sort your list (or use a TreeSet).